# How to get yarn command output in github actions

Tags: command, github-actions, npm-audit

Im working on adding the output of yarn audit as a PR comment.
The problem is that all the output of $log is not displayed.

here is the code

```
      - name: Run audit
        id: audit
        run: |
          log="$(yarn audit)"
          echo "::set-output name=log::$log"

      - name: Create comment
        uses: peter-evans/create-or-update-comment@v2
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        with:
          issue-number: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
          body: ${{ steps.audit.outputs.log }}
```

now comment is only shows `yarn audit v1.22.19`

The result I want is this.

```
yarn audit v1.22.19
0 vulnerabilities found - Packages audited: 768
✨  Done in 0.47s.
```

Comment: have you tried to redirect the output to a file, like `yarn audit > output.txt` then add the file as the body of the comment?

Comment: @Matteo I solved it like this
Thanks for your help!! 

```
          yarn audit > audit-log.txt
          log="$(cat output.txt)"
          log="${log//'%'/'%25'}"
          log="${log//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
          log="${log//$'\r'/'%0D'}" 
          echo "::set-output name=log::$log"
```

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this.

`yarn audit > audit-log.txt log="$(cat output.txt)" log="${log//'%'/'%25'}" log="${log//$'\n'/'%0A'}" log="${log//$'\r'/'%0D'}" echo "::set-output name=log::$log"`